# VBA Code to Update data from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 Excel Files

**Tracker**

```
**Grp**   **Current Status**   **Prior Status**      **Any Changes**
  grp1      Implementation       Approved               Change 
  grp2      Approved             Approved               No Change 
  grp3      Doc Recd             Doc Recd               No Change
  grp4      Implementation       Approved               Change
```

**Inventory**

```
 **Grp**    **Current Status**        **Col02**     
  grp1           Approved               789
  grp2           Approved               123
  grp3           Doc Recd               456
  grp4           Approved               000
```

I am very new to VBA , I am not sure how to write a query , so approaching the community for help .

In **Trackers** file if  **Grp**  has different values in **status**  and **Prior Status** then **Any Changes** will be considered as change.

If **Current Status** & **Prior Status** are same it will be considered as **No Change**

for below example grp1 & grp4  **Current Status** has changed from **Prior Status**

I just want code :

1. That Checks **Change** in  **Any Changes** column  "If Change"
2. Then grp1 & grp4 **Current Status** from **Tracker** file should be updated in **Inventory** file **Current Status** column based on the Group Name.

Note: Sometimes there might be extra spaces between the both file **grp** field.

I do this manually and update records from Tracker to Inventory everyday.

VBA Code should activate respective files and columns and change values.

Code i tried didn't work attaching below

```
Sub Lookup()

Dim rnge as Range
Dim cl As Range


Workbooks("Trackers 040620 PM.xlsx").Activate
Worksheets("Central").Activate
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 1 To lastrow

     If Range("g" & i).Value = "Change" Then
        srchval = Trim(Range("d" & i).Value)
        chgval = Trim(Range("e" & i).Value)

            Workbooks("Interim Inventory Tracker - All States 040620 v1.xlsx").Activate
            Sheets("Main Data input").Activate

             get_row_number = Workbooks("Interim Inventory Tracker - All States 040620 v1.xlsx"). _
                              Sheets("Main Data input").Range("D:D").Find( _
              What:=srchval, _
              LookIn:=xlValues, _
              LookAt:=xlPart, _
              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
              SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
              MatchCase:=True _
              ).Row

        If get_row_number = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            Workbooks("Interim Inventory Tracker - All States 040620 v1.xlsx").Activate
            Sheets("Main Data input").Range("H" & get_row_number).Value = chgval
            chgval = ""
        End If
        Workbooks("Trackers 040620 PM.xlsx").Activate
        Worksheets("Central").Activate
     End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Define didn't work please - Did you get an error? If so, what error and on what line? Did the code run and seem to do nothing? Did the code run and do something unexpected?

Comment: Couple of notes: You should not rely on active books/sheets. Store them as varaibles so you can be explicit. Your `get_row_number` is error prone. What if the value you are searching for is not found? You are better off storing the range from your `.Find` and accessing the `Range.Row` property so you can handle unfound cell errors.

Comment: @urdearboy code runs till If statement and directly goes to end if, doesn’t enter inside the if code.

Comment: @urdearboy I’m not sure on how to do that. I just googled and got this code, I did do some couple of changes like sheet name, range etc, but It didn’t work

Answer (score 0):

Try

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Lookup()

    Const WB_TRACKER = "Trackers 040620 PM.xlsx"
    Const WB_INVENTORY = "Interim Inventory Tracker - All States 040620 v1.xlsx"

    Dim wbTracker As Workbook, wsTracker As Worksheet
    Dim wbInventory As Workbook, wsInventory As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iRow As Long, count As Long
    Dim srchval As String, chgval As String

    Set wbTracker = Workbooks(WB_TRACKER)
    Set wsTracker = wbTracker.Sheets("Central")

    Set wbInventory = Workbooks(WB_INVENTORY)
    Set wsInventory = wbInventory.Sheets("Main Data input")

    iLastRow = wsTracker.Range("G" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    count = 0
    For iRow = 2 To iLastRow
        If wsTracker.Range("G" & iRow).Value = "Change" Then

            srchval = Trim(wsTracker.Range("D" & iRow).Value)
            chgval = Trim(wsTracker.Range("E" & iRow).Value)

            Set rng = wsInventory.Range("D:D").Find( _
                    What:=srchval, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=True)

            If rng Is Nothing Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                wsInventory.Range("H" & rng.Row) = chgval
                count = count + 1
            End If
         End If
     Next
     MsgBox iLastRow - 1 & " rows scanned on " & wsTracker.Name & vbCr & _
            count & " rows updated on " & wsInventory.Name, vbInformation
End Sub
```